# Show progress bar with percentage on click of button

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

In my project a lot of procedures are running which are taking time.
I need to show a progress bar with percentage of completion on click of a button in Oracle APEX (v5.1 or more) when those procedures are being called.
So that user can get to know how much it has been completed.

I have tried [plugin](https://apex.world/ords/f?p=100:710:2916154737971::::P710_PLG_ID:apex.modern.nprogress) from apex.world. But it is not showing percentage and I have not succeeded.

Comment: Alternatively, you might want to check out this blog post on [apex.oracle.com](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/germancommunities/apexcommunity/tipp/2201/index-en.html)